# How do I sell equipment?

Tags: stardew-valley

I've done some mine delving and I've amassed a selection of equipment that's frankly useless to me; some outdated weapons, shoes, and rings. While I know that I could dispose of them with the inventory trash, I would prefer to sell them. However, I can't put them in the shipping box.

Comment: You can sell equipment to shops, such as Pierre's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to sell your unwanted equipment to the Adventurer's Guild once unlocked.

[This](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Weapons) page on the Wiki also gives you a buy/sell price for each weapon/type you want to sell.

Comment: The Adventurer's Guild will buy the equipment but Pierre's will not.

Comment: Is it possible to sell these useless slingshots?  The adventurer's guild does not buy them.

Comment: I haven't found anyone that will purchase it from me. So I scrapped the first one and kept the Master one in a chest.

Comment: The Adventurer's Guild doesn't seem to buy rings

Answer (score -1):

Pierre's Shop and the Adventurer's Guild will take your equipment